# Join tables on a partially matched columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to join two tables on a partially matched columns in SQL?

For example:

`T1.column` has the string `'c/ar'` and `T2.column` has the string `'ar'` and I want the tables to be joined in this case.

I tried

```
select column2, 
       column3 
from T1 join T2 on T1.column like '%T2.column';
```

but it returns 0 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to concatenate `'%'` with column `T2.column` and not with the string value `'T2.column'`:

```
like ('%' || T2.column)
```

or

```
like CONCAT('%', T2.column)
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you may use `strpos` function as

```
select column1, column2 
  from T1 
  join T2 on strpos(T1.column1,T2.column2)>0;
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/YQTJ10548)

*The PostgreSQL strpos() function is used to find the position, from where the substring is being matched within the string.*

> **Syntax:**
>   *strpos( < string > , < substring >)*

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `RIGHT()` and `LENGTH()` functions since you are checking if `T2.Column` exists in the end of `T1.Column`

```
ON RIGHT(T1.Column1, LENGTH(T2.Column2)) = T2.Column2
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=e03b6954ba75ef879fc529f8ea8dc371)**